# Service stops working, error in web.config: cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key att name set to 'scripthandlerfactory'

Tags: .net, wcf

My web service (wcf) stopped working all of a sudden.

I compared my web.config with older versions and they all have the exact same elements so I am very confused why all of a sudden I am getting this error message.

Have any of you run into this problem before?

> Filename: web.config Line Number 151 Error: cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'ScriptHandlerFactory' ?

Comment: Did the title really need to be that long??

Comment: Please share your web.config file with us.  That'll be a great place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always get burned by this on deployment, and its not my web.config.  99% of the time it has to do with the parent websites web.config being inherited to the child webapplication.  Has anything been changed on that?

What I usually do is add a `<remove>` tag for what ever section is giving me the error, but for some that cant be done (im thinking group sections) and just need to be given a different name.